# Reverse string omitting special characters and numbers

Tags: python

Practicing python on codewars ran into a question that I just couldnt figure out.

Task
Given a string str, reverse it omitting all non-alphabetic characters.

Example

```
For str = "krishan", the output should be "nahsirk".

For str = "ultr53o?n", the output should be "nortlu".
```

Input/Output
[input] string str

A string consists of lowercase latin letters, digits and symbols.

[output] a string

I used the extended slice operator to reverse the string but I can not figure out how to get rid of the special characters

```
def reverse_letter(string):
    return string [::-1]
```

Comment: Use regex  ..https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/regex

Comment: why the downvote? looks like a legit question

Comment: Iterate over the reversed string and only keep non-special characters

Answer (score 1):

Reverse string with `[::-1]` and check chars are alphabetic with `.isalpha()`

```
string = "ultr53o?n"
print(''.join(c for c in string[::-1] if c.isalpha()))
```

> `'nortlu'`

Comment: don't, you have a specific function to check if it is alphanumeric or alphabetic, use that function

Comment: Oooooh, I see since we are checking if the characts can be upper or lower we are eliminating the possibilities for numbers and special characters.

Answer (score 1):

Using Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re

data = ["krishan", "ultr53o?n"]

for i in data:
    print(re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z]", "", i)[::-1])   # `[^a-zA-Z]` Removes everything except letters.
```

**Output:**

```
nahsirk
nortlu
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by following steps:

1. filter alphabetical characters, using `filter`
2. join result list to create a new string, using `join`
3. reverse result string

Here's the code.

```py
def reverse_letter(string):
    filtered_string = filter(lambda c: c.isalpha(), string)
    result = ''.join(filtered_string)
    return result[::-1]
```

And another solution is here.

1. iterate string in reverse order and get a list of alphabetical characters
2. join the result list, using `join`

```py
def reverse_letter(string):
    char_list = [c for c in string[::-1] if c.isalpha()]
    return ''.join(char_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it, just clean the string before reverting it (e.g. with list comprehension, strings can be iterated like if they were lists)

```
def reverse_and_clean(string):
    return ''.join([s for s in string if s.isalnum()])[::-1]
```

Check the is.... functions to get the specific one you want for characters, e.g. isalpha (if you only want alphabetic) isalnum() if only alphanumeric etc.